# Cannot reach resource in Jersey tutorial

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I am completely new to Jersey and am having trouble with getting it to work.

I first built a project in Eclipse using the Maven archetype for Jersey 2, jersey-quickstart-webapp (or something along those lines).

I then converted that project to a Dynamic Web Application so that I could run it on my Tomcat server on Eclipse.

After doing all of that, I cannot get the 'myresource' URL to work. 
'http://localhost:8080/Testing/webapi/myresource' shows nothing.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.personal.Testing.Testing</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Resource class:

```
package com.personal.Testing.Testing;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    /**
     * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
     * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
     *
     * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a tutorial (https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey2-hello-world-example/#webxml)

"First, run maven to create you war file.

Then hot deploy war file to your tomcat server..."

Then try hitting your URL. Should work just fine.

It seems you may be doing a simple run for the application you created in Eclipse. In that case, the application will not be deployed to you Web Server (Tomcat in your case).

**You need to deploy the application as a war in the server for the URL to work.**